# Get Strings from DataRow the DRY way

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been searching everywhere but I can't seem to find a good method. Currently I've been getting a `DataRowCollection` from my SQL table, but I'd like to have a more efficient way to get strings from the cells.

This is what I have to do currently:

```
foreach (DataRow row in DataRowCollection)
    string firstName = row["FirstName"].toString();
    string lastName = row["LastName"].toString();
    string email = row["Email"].toString();
    etc...
}
```

I've tried creating a list with a list of strings, but it didn't seem to function the way I'd like it too.
 But I'd like to have something without having to use "toString()" like so...

```
foreach (DataRow row in DataRowCollection)
    string firstName = row["FirstName"];
    string lastName = row["LastName"];
    string email = row["Email"];
}
```

I feel like this would make things a bit tidier so I wouldn't have to set variables and just use `row["column"]` when I get their values.

What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: `string firstName = Convert.ToString(row["FirstName"]);`

Comment: Have you considered using generics or a mapping library to address your DRY concerns?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't get it to work properly. And I can't really map it to a class because there are different tables with different columns. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

Use [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) from `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` for strongly-typed data access.

```
var firstName = row.Field<string>("FirstName");
var lastName = row.Field<string>("LastName");
var email = row.Field<string>("Email");
```

EDIT: To convert `DataTable` to `List<List<string>>`, use Linq

Example

```
var list = dataTable.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(dr => dr.ItemArray.Cast<string>())
    .ToList();
```

or nested foreach

```
var list = new List<List<string>>();
foreach (var row in DataRowCollection) {
    var subList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
        subList.Add(item.ToString());
    list.Add(subList);
}
```

Comment: `.Field<string>` is longer than `.ToString()`.

Comment: @JLRishe but consistent for all types, not only string, make things simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess what I'm looking for is a way to get all the strings at once. I'm not even sure if there is a list that can link names to their values, like 'list["name"] = "John";' Most of my background is with JavaScript which is probably why I'm so picky about all these data conversions.